# iOS : App distribution through Amazon S3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, amazon-s3

How to distribute app through Amazon S3. I have an ipa which is an Enterprise ipa, i want to distribute it through Amazon S3. any articles or guidelines will help. Appreciate it!